# Can a scatter plot be used for identifying the interaction terms for multiple linear regression model?

Tags: r, regression, scatter-plot

I know we can deduce a correlation using scatterplot between the variables. But can it help in identify interaction terms in multiple regression?

Answer (score 1):

There are many manual ways of doing it, but I can show you two convenient libraries/functions that may be up your alley. They come from the `visreg` and `sjPlot` libraries. First, we can load the libraries and fit a regression model with R's `iris` dataset.

```
#### Library ####
library(visreg)
library(sjPlot)

#### Fit Model ####
fit <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width*Sepal.Width,
          iris)
```

To plot with `visreg`, you just specify the fit, the variable of interest, and a "by" argument to split the values of Petal.Width up by different values of Sepal.Width. I switched it here to `gg=T` to make it a `ggplot2` object:

```
#### Visualize with Visreg ####
visreg(fit,
       "Petal.Width",
       by = "Sepal.Width",
       gg=T)
```

[image]

Here I use `plot_model` by specifying I wan't an interaction with "int" and split the values of the interaction by their mean and SD.

```
#### Visualize with Plot_Model ####
plot_model(fit,
           type = "int",
           mdrt.values = "meansd")
```

[image]

You can see from all of these plots that the interaction between predictors isn't very strong, as the line of fit doesn't vary by much. To visualize a more meaningful change, we can fit the following regression with the `mtcars` data. I have also added in data points this time with `show.data` to get a scatterplot:

```
#### More Varied Regression ####
fit2 <- lm(mpg ~ hp*disp,
           mtcars)
plot_model(fit2,
           type="int",
           mdrt.values = "meansd",
           show.data = T,
           axis.title = c("Horsepower","Miles per Gallon"),
           colors = c("black","steelblue","darkblue"),
           title = "Interaction Between Horsepower and Miles per Gallon on MPG")
```

[image]

Here we can see engine displacement really changes how much horsepower affects miles per gallon for cars.

Comment: That's very detailed.But can we use scatterplot to check which variables are significant to be included in the model before running regression?

Comment: You can only eyeball from the plots whether they should be or not. You can see from the weak and strong interactions Ive plotted what that can look likr. Only the actual regression output can tell you for sure.

Comment: Sometimes a scatterplot without modeling can be misleading. For example there can be a case of two predictors by themselves having very linear/strong correlations with the outcome but if these two predictors are also strongly correlated to each other it can lead to suppression effects, which again can only be ascertained from the regression fit.